# Regex to Match Phrase ending with a question mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a javascript regex that'll match an exact phrase that ends with a question mark, but isn't wrapped in quotes. So far I have this, which matches the phrase "some phrase", but I can't figure out how to match "some phrase?". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(?<!"|')\some phrase\b(?!"|')
```

Answer (score 2):

Lookbehinds don't exist in JavaScript. Use the following pattern:
`(?:[^"']|^)(some phrase\?)(?!["'])`. `[^"']|^` means: any non-quote character *or* the beginning of a string.

Example:

```
var text = "....";
var pattern = /(?:[^"']|^)(some phrase\?)(?!["'])/;
var string = text.match(pattern);
var desiredString = string[1]; //Get the grouped text

var patternWithNQuoteGrouped = /([^"']|^)(some phrase\?)(?!["'])/;//Notice: No ?:
var replaceString = text.replace(patternWithNQuoteGrouped, '$1$2');
//$1 = non-quote character $2 = matched phrase
```

The parentheses around the phrase mark a referable group. `(?:` means: Create a group, but dereference it. To refer back to it, see the example code. Because lookbehinds don't exist in JavaScript, it's not possible to create a pattern which checks whether a prefix does not exist.

Comment: +1 Yes, the problem is that javascript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: @trinithis `|$` is not needed, because `(?!["'])` means: Match if the next character is not a quote. Well, if the next character doesn't exist, it's certainly not a quote.

Comment: This one actually got me closer with the suggested fixes, but it's still selecting an extra character before the phrase. If I remove the (?:[^"']|^) part it ignores the extra character. But obviously won't do the right match.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Extended answer with explnation. In short, you have to refer to groups, because JavaScript don't support look-behinds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var expr = /(^|(?!["']).)(some phrase\?)($|(?!["']).)/;
if (expr.test(searchText)) {
    var matchingPhrase = RegExp.$2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/zCUsg/

Comment: This should be the correct answer (Vivin, I think you submitted yours too fast, and added an extra question mark, and the quotes too), but I'm wondering what the "phrase" can be: just a sequence of random characters, or something that is actually undestandable in english?

In this last case, CodeMonkey may add \b at the beginning of the regular expression.

Comment: That got me closer. This worked: (^|(?!["']))some phrase/?($|(?!["']).). The original was also grabbing a character before and after the phrase.

Comment: Actually I just tried this in my app and it kept giving me a syntax error.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - To get only the phrase, you can wrap the phrase in parens and look at the resulting capture.  Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/zCUsg/